# What does this Zurb Foundation 6 mixin @include xy-grid() mean?

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

What does this Zurb Foundation 6 mixin mean

```
 @include xy-grid();
```

Which one does it define, grid-x or  grid-y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@include xy-grid;`
This only does display: flex.

You can also use the mixin with arguments to make it vertical (grid-y):

`@include xy-grid($direction: vertical, $wrap: false);`

API docs: https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html#xy-grid